# long script include GO commands - undo if fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge sql script that makes a lot of changes in my db scheme and in my data. The script includes GO commands.

Is there any way to execute the script and undo it in case of an any error?

I cannot wrap everything in transaction since there is GO commands.

Comment: Transactions can span multiple batches.

Comment: @Martin SmithL I wrapped all the script with BEGIN TRY - BEGIN TRANSACTION but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap multiple batches in a transaction, you are wrong about that, but truth is that a complex upgrade script is unlikely to be possible to execute in one single transaction. Your best solution would to take a backup and if the script fails restore the database from the backup.

Comment: Thats what I am doing - backup and restore over and over again, but this takes a lot of time.. I didn't understand from your answer, can I wrap everything in a BEGIN TRY - BEGIN TRANSACTION ?

Comment: Have you ever used Red Gate SQL Compare? You can do some complex stuff with that. A backup should always happen anyway, but with some controlling code the database requires no downtime for the rollback (just some blocking).

Comment: You can wrap everything in a BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT, but not in a BEGIN TRY, a TRY/CATCH block still has to occur in a single batch.

Comment: How do you run the upgrade script? sqlcmd for instance when started with `-b` will abort the script at first batch with an error and set the `errorlevel` to 1 so you can use this in scripts.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: I am using the sql management studio in order to execute the script. What is -b? and how can I use SQL Compare in order to do it? Does it free tool?

Comment: `-b` is a command line option for `sqlcmd`. You already have `sqlcmd` in your instalation. Management Studio can do the same by adding `:on error exit` at the beginning of the script and enabling sqcmd mode in SSMS, see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use SET XACT_ABORT ON. This is batch aborting and does an automatic rollback. So...

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRAN
GO
--DO stuff
GO
IF XACT_STATE() = 1
  --do more stuff
GO
IF XACT_STATE() = 1
  --do more stuff
GO
....
GO
IF XACT_STATE() = 1
  COMMIT TRAN
GO
```

You can combine this with TRY/CATCH per batch and/or use a temp table to control flow (as per Red Gate SQL Compare scripts)

Comment: @Naor: it tests to see if a transaction is still open. SET XACT_ABORT ON will rollback back so XACT_STATE() = 0. You could use @@TRANCOUNT but XACT_STATE() is more useful for this.

Comment: What I am asking is if can I wrap everything with:
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRAN
GO
[ALL SQL SCRIPT]
GO
IF XACT_STATE() = 1
  COMMIT TRAN
GO

Without the checkings you made in the middle of the script?

Comment: @Naor: if step 3 fails because step 2 bombed out, then yes. If not, the change on step 3 will happen anyway. Download a trial of Red Gate SQL Compare and see how this does scripts.

Comment: Also consider running the scripts in sqlcmd mode and add an `:on error exit` at the beginning. This will stop the script shell (SSMS or SQLCMD) from continuing across to the next batch if one errored, eliminating the need to check for XACT_STATE() on every batch. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: good idea. I rely on SQL Compare for this so haven't had to do it manually.

Comment: I cannot insert IF XACT_STATE() = 1 between all my GO's commands since I have many of them in my script and the script is very long. I don't understrand how SQL Compare will help me.

Comment: @Naor: I said "as per Red Gate SQL Compare scripts" above. See how it generates them.